# Best way to choose which columns to index to improve performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, index

I use a MSSQL Database for my web application and now the user audit(`USER_AUDIT`) records in the application have crossed beyond 5 million records/rows. Every day the performance of the application is degrading and the queries for the audit table are pretty straight forward from the UI.

The default sorting on the data is on the `TimeStamp` i.e. the time when the record was created so I was wondering if adding an `INDEX` on the `TimeStamp` column would improve the performance of the application or because the the `ID` column(Incremental IDs) already has the `INDEX` on it, its sufficient and would not improve the performance any further.

Also sometimes the records need to be filtered using the `username` which is also one of the columns in the same table but because the user names are not unique I was wondering if it would help at all to add `INDEX` to that column as well.

The clustered index is on the `ID` column on the table - Would it be helpful if I change the `Clustered INDEX` to be on a different column

Or

Based on the above information would it be of any help to add `Non-clustered Indexes` to either `TimeStamp` or `Username` or both columns

I come from a programming background with very limited knowledge of the Database management so please pardon any missing information and please feel free to let me know if I need to add more information to the Question.

I would really appreciate it even if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you paste the query plan : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ ?
When we have the query plan we can analyse your problem in way more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Determining indexes for tables is not easy. I can offer some general guidelines that will help, but the specifics are going to be up to you to determine through testing on your systems with your queries.

The first, and most important, index you set is your clustered index. You only get one, so you want to make it right. Further, the key on your clustered index is also going to be the key for looking up all your non-clustered indexes. So, generally, you want to try satisfy three general criteria for your clustered index. First, the cluster should go on the column, or columns, that define the most commonly used path to the data. You don't say how the data is most commonly filtered above, so I can't make a recommendation based on that. Second, because the clustered index key is used for lookups in other indexes, as much as you can, you want it to be as small a data type as possible. You'll frequently see an ID column like you have because it satisfies this. However, don't get hung up on this. If a 'Name' column is the most frequently used path to the data, even though it's a wider key than an int, it can still be the clustered index. Further, the clustered index has to be unique. That's not to say the column must be unique. SQL Server can make the cluster unique internally if it has to. Yes, this adds overhead, so unique data is preferred, but again, driven by reality, not arbitrary rules.

Nonclustered indexes. Use as few as you can. However, create them as you need them. From the sounds of things, sorting on timestamp frequently, you might want an index there. However, this is where things get fun, that doesn't mean it will get used to sort the data. It depends on the other filtering criteria and how the data is being retrieved, which columns, the exact WHERE clause, etc. Same thing goes for creating a nonclustered index on Name. It could be a good choice. However, what other columns are being retrieved?
As was already mentioned, if you add a nonclustered index, but it only satisfies the filter criteria for the query, you'll still have to go to the clustered index to look up the rest of the columns. This is fixed by either adding additional columns to the nonclustered key (although, only do that if they're also used for filtering), or by using the INCLUDE key word.

All of this has to be tested by looking at the execution plans for your query. That will show you which indexes are being used and how they are used. So plan on pulling that information out.

Yeah, this is an enormous topic and I've only scratched the surface here. I have a 900 page book on query tuning and a 600 page book on execution plans. There's that much to talk about.

Comment: Thanks a lot Grant, I really appreciate the guidance

Answer (score 2):

A clustered index on a timestamp column (a temporal data type such as datetime, not rowversion) is often a good choice for audit tables. This will help avoid full scans when date range criteria are specified in queries and the incremental value helps improve buffer efficiency during inserts.

An additional non-clustered index on `UserName` will help avoid a full scan when a relatively small percentage of rows qualify. Also, since the clustered index key is implicitly included in non-clustered indexes as the row locator, queries that specify both UserName and timestamp will likely perform better.

If the `ID` identity column is the primary key and not referenced by a foreign key, I suggest it be removed entirely. Audit tables are not really relational in nature and, IMHO, do not require a primary key.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan, really appreciate the information. You are right, the ID column is not a foreign key anywhere and does not get referenced any where else either. I will set the Clustered key on the TimeStamp column.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, if you filter on Username you should add a non-clustered index on username.

Make sure you also use the [include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure) statement for all the columns you are selecting or joining on.

If the user query is also order by timestamp, you can create the index like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_USER_AUDIT_Username 
ON Username(Timestamp DESC, Username ASC)  
INCLUDE (/*other columns*/);
```

This index will allow you to seek instead of a table scan on timestamp and username. Assuming you have `order by Timestamp desc` you don't need an additional sort.

This way you have 1 index for both of your problems. Make sure the sorting of index is correct, if your query does `ORDER BY Timestamp DESC` the index should also be created with `DESC` order.

Sometimes it's better to create 2 indexes for both issues.

The `include` statement helps when you have key-lookups in your execution plan.
By including extra columns, you don't have to access to clusterd index to find the values of the included columns, because they are included.

Comment: Thanks a lot Preben. I appreciate you providing a sample index create query. I have a question though - Why is the index on Username column and including Timestamp + Username in the brackets - what does that achieve?

Comment: Also, whats the benefit of INCLUDE(/* other columns */) - does it help when other columns are added to the filter criteria

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please share the execution plan if you wan't a more detailed answer on what index you should create.